# DBUpdate exception was unhandled

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

im trying to insert into a [tbl.three] that contains foreign keys from [tbl.One] and [tbl.Two]. I have populated the dropdownlist with the primary key from [tbl.One] and [tbl.Two] in MVC 4. it is showing in the dropdownlist
 but when i click submit, it shows the error below.

**Please help , thank you for your time**

this is my database with the given tables:

```
Create database [ForeignKey]

Create table[tbl.One]
(
   [Occupation] Varchar(20) Primary Key,
   [Area] Varchar(20)
)

insert into [tbl.One] values('IT', 'India')
insert into [tbl.One] values('MCSD', 'China')
insert into [tbl.One] values('MCSE', 'Maimi')
insert into [tbl.One] values('Cisco', 'Hawaii')

Create table[tbl.Two]
(
   [Address] Varchar(20) Primary Key,
   [Surburb] Varchar(20)
)

insert into [tbl.Two] values('18 Jet Park','Florida')
insert into [tbl.Two] values('25 High Road','Hamberg')
insert into [tbl.Two] values('1 Main Reef','Discovery')
insert into [tbl.Two] values('3 Kink Road','Constancia')

Create table[tbl.Three]
(
   [id] int Primary key,
   [Name] Varchar(20),
   [Surname] Varchar(20),
   [Occupation] Varchar(20) foreign key references [tbl.One]([Occupation]),
   [Occupation1] Varchar(20) foreign key references [tbl.One]([Occupation]),
   [Address] Varchar(20) foreign key references [tbl.Two]([Address]),
)
```

This is my Error :

[image]

This is my Controller code:

```
 public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private ForeignKeyEntities db = new ForeignKeyEntities();

        //
        // GET: /Home/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var tbl_three = db.tbl_Three.Include(t => t.tbl_One).Include(t => t.tbl_One1).Include(t => t.tbl_Two);
            return View(tbl_three.ToList());
        }

        //
        // GET: /Home/Details/5

        public ActionResult Details(int id = 0)
        {
            tbl_Three tbl_three = db.tbl_Three.Find(id);
            if (tbl_three == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(tbl_three);
        }

        //
        // GET: /Home/Create

        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            ViewBag.Occupation = new SelectList(db.tbl_One, "Occupation", "Area");
            ViewBag.Occupation1 = new SelectList(db.tbl_One, "Occupation", "Area");
            ViewBag.Address = new SelectList(db.tbl_Two, "Address", "Surburb");
            return View();
        }

        //
        // POST: /Home/Create

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create(tbl_Three tbl_three)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.tbl_Three.Add(tbl_three);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            ViewBag.Occupation = new SelectList(db.tbl_One, "Occupation", "Area", tbl_three.Occupation);
            ViewBag.Occupation1 = new SelectList(db.tbl_One, "Occupation", "Area", tbl_three.Occupation1);
            ViewBag.Address = new SelectList(db.tbl_Two, "Address", "Surburb", tbl_three.Address);
            return View(tbl_three);
        }

        //
        // GET: /Home/Edit/5

        public ActionResult Edit(int id = 0)
        {
            tbl_Three tbl_three = db.tbl_Three.Find(id);
            if (tbl_three == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            ViewBag.Occupation = new SelectList(db.tbl_One, "Occupation", "Area", tbl_three.Occupation);
            ViewBag.Occupation1 = new SelectList(db.tbl_One, "Occupation", "Area", tbl_three.Occupation1);
            ViewBag.Address = new SelectList(db.tbl_Two, "Address", "Surburb", tbl_three.Address);
            return View(tbl_three);
        }

        //
        // POST: /Home/Edit/5

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Edit(tbl_Three tbl_three)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(tbl_three).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            ViewBag.Occupation = new SelectList(db.tbl_One, "Occupation", "Area", tbl_three.Occupation);
            ViewBag.Occupation1 = new SelectList(db.tbl_One, "Occupation", "Area", tbl_three.Occupation1);
            ViewBag.Address = new SelectList(db.tbl_Two, "Address", "Surburb", tbl_three.Address);
            return View(tbl_three);
        }

        //
        // GET: /Home/Delete/5

        public ActionResult Delete(int id = 0)
        {
            tbl_Three tbl_three = db.tbl_Three.Find(id);
            if (tbl_three == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(tbl_three);
        }

        //
        // POST: /Home/Delete/5

        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
        {
            tbl_Three tbl_three = db.tbl_Three.Find(id);
            db.tbl_Three.Remove(tbl_three);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            db.Dispose();
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
}
```

this is my View(Create) code:

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>tbl_Three</legend>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Surname)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Surname)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Surname)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Occupation, "tbl_One")
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownList("Occupation", String.Empty)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Occupation)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Occupation1, "tbl_One1")
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownList("Occupation1", String.Empty)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Occupation1)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Address, "tbl_Two")
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownList("Address", String.Empty)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Address)
    </div>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
```

}

Comment: click on the view details and see the inner exception

Comment: give us a picture of your inner exception. May it is a type problem.

Comment: {"Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK__tbl.Thre__3213E83FCEF90462'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.tbl.Three'. The duplicate key value is (0).\r\nThe statement has been terminated."}

Comment: that is what the inner exception says

Comment: You try to insert in your datable a row with a primary key which already exists, so it doesn't work. Try to change the insert value on primary key

Comment: Im trying to populate objects with data from other tables, which then inserts into one table, what do you suggest?

Comment: According to me the best way to fix your problem is to put an auto-increment to your Id in tbl.Three. Check this link for more details : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21168964/sql-insert-failing-violation-of-primary-key-constraint

Answer (score 1):

This line

```
db.tbl_Three.Add(tbl_three);
```

is adding an item `tbl_three` to a database `tbl_Three` which already contains an item with `tbl_three`'s Primary Key (which is not allowed).

The problem arises because your `Create` view isn't being given a *new* `tbl_three` but an existing one. You can create a new `tbl_three` with the properties of the original, and then `Add` that - this will ensure that it has a unique Primary Key.

Answer (score 1):

The Id column is Primary Key and looks like you are inserting duplicate Id values to the table for multiple records.

What you should do is to change the table creation to use [Identity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775.aspx) for the Primary key column. With this, you do not need to insert the value of the Id column. Everytime you add a new record,SQL server will automatically add the new ID value

```
Create table[tbl.Three]
(
   [id] int Primary key  IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
   [Name] Varchar(20),
   [Surname] Varchar(20),
   [Occupation] Varchar(20) foreign key references [tbl.One]([Occupation]),
   [Occupation1] Varchar(20) foreign key references [tbl.One]([Occupation]),
   [Address] Varchar(20) foreign key references [tbl.Two]([Address]),
)
```